# Controlling dropdown menu from hidden webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a hidden webview loading a html login form which contains a drop down menu from which the user can specify it´s type. I have a segmented control set up and want it to select from the html drop down menu, but can´t get it to work. The relevant code looks like this:

```
//The html code with the drop down menu. 

<div class="login_formtable">
    <label class="login_label">I am</label>
    <div id="loginselect" style="clear:both:">
            <select name="usertype" size="1"  id="usertype" class="select1" >     
 <option value="0"  selected="selected">Staff</option>
 <option value="1" >Student</option>
 <option value="2" >Parent</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this.

If you want to use check boxes, you need to create your own UI using `UIButton` or `UIPickerView`.

If you try this in `UIWebView`, you cannot fetch the selected values in `UIWebView`.

I guess this [link](http://iphoneprobsolutions.blogspot.in/) might help you.

Comment: Do you mean it is impossible or that I should use UIButtons instead of a segmented controller?

Comment: probably you can do it with javascript. I m not sure.... but no point in doing that. You should use iphone's UI, if you are creating app for iPhone. if you want to redirect it to another page or anything. It will only redirect to another page in html, not to another view controller.

Comment: I dont want the segmented control to redirect anything. I want it to select a value in the drop down menu on the webpage

Comment: for selection, you have `UIPickerView`, you won't be able to fetch that selected value from `UIWebView`.

Comment: you can't. you need to create your own view in xcode view controller.